# how to get character array to print out in one line and not multiple in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, printing, char

How do i print out character array (msg) in c++? My output prints the words i've encrypted on different lines instead of just one. Also, "Enter a line of text or 'done'" ends up repeating itself. I assumed its because of the space between the words. How do I fix this? Any suggestion would be helpful!

```
int main()
{
    ofstream outputFile;
    string fileName; //initiate variables
    char msg[100]; 
    int i;
    std::cout<< "Enter file name to encrypt: "; //get file name from user
    std::cin >> fileName; //save file name 
    outputFile.open(fileName);
    while(true){
    std::cout<< "Enter a line of text or '" << "done" << "' to quit: "; //get line of text from user
    std::cin>> msg; //send line of text to message array 
        if (msg[0] == 'd' && msg[1] == 'o' && msg[2] == 'n' && msg[3] == 'e'){//check if done is input
            break; //if done is entered, break program
        }
        else{
            for(i = 0; (i < 100 && msg[i] != '\0'); i++){ //loops thru encrypting each letter
                msg[i] = msg[i] + 1; //encrypt text 
            }
            outputFile << msg << endl; //send encrypted string/message to file from user
            std::cout << "Encrypted message: " << msg << endl; //print encrypted text to screen
        }
   }
    outputFile.close(); //close file
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using an array of `char` instead of `std::string`? The fact that the file name is a `string` indicates that you are aware of C++-style strings.

Comment: For the `break`: replace AND `&&` by OR `||` !!

Comment: Besides, please give an example of simple input and wrong output

Comment: @Damien You suggest breaking for every word that starts with `'d'` **or** that has `'o'` as its second letter **or** that has `'n'` as its third letter **or** that has `'e'` as its fourth? The use of `&&` there looks correct to me (but it is missing a check for the fifth character being `'\0'`).

Comment: @JaMiT Right. Sorry, I read too fast.

Comment: Thanks I will try the suggestions. And the code is for a class. The teacher told us to use a character array. I thought of using a string too because it made more sense

Comment: @Damien my input output looks like this Enter file name to encrypt: e.txt                                                                                              
Enter a line of text or 'done' to quit: stop it                                                                                
Encrypted message: tupq                                                                                                        
Enter a line of text or 'done' to quit: Encrypted message: ju

Comment: I tested your code. It seems to work fine. The only issue, if it is, is that the result is added at the end of the existing file, the old content is not supressed. To avoid that, I needed to use `outputFile.open(fileName, ios_base::out);` It looks strange as normally, `ios_base::out` is selected by default. I did not have time to analyse it

Answer (score 0):

Your code uses [`operator>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) to get the user input. This is a word-based formatted input function. It skips leading whitespace, then extracts a sequence of non-whitespace characters. That is, it extracts the next word of input. After getting the next word, you process it, start a new line of output, prompt the user for more input, then repeat. When there is more than word per line, the computer does not wait for more input (despite the prompt), and you see the output you describe.

Since you are looking for a line of input, you should use an API that *gets* an entire *line* of input instead of just one word. Ready for the surprising name of this API? It's called `getline()`, or more precisely [`std::istream::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) since you are stuck using character arrays instead of strings.

```
std::cin.getline(msg, 100);
```

Using `std::string` would not change the results, but it would make the documentation a little easier for me to find. The [version of `operator>>` for strings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) is also word-based. The line-getting API for strings is a a free function, [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

---

Suggested input for one of your tests:

```
Done
DONE
donegal is in Ireland
done?
done!
done
```